# Assign rules to sub account in Mandrill

Tags: mandrill

I have a project with an single API key in Mandrill. It has three sub-accounts: production, staging, development. I have created a rule that rejects all requests that don't match a small list of domains and I want to apply that rule to both the staging and development sub accounts. The idea is to not accidentally spam clients while we are testing.

I don't see how I can apply the rule to different sub accounts. Is it possible? If not, and I need to create different APIs for each environment, can someone explain when to use sub-account vs when to create different API keys.

As a bonus, when an email matches a rule, is it possible to reroute it to a specified address instead of rejecting it?

Comment: It probably would have been better to ask these as separate questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use separate sub accounts for tracking different systems in a multi-tenant environment (eg you are acting as a service provider for multiple customers or departments via the same Mandrill account).

In your case, I would definitely use separate API keys for each each environment. The main feature you would potentially want to take advantage of is to be able to set one of those keys (eg staging) as a "test key" such that the emails don't ever get sent, they just get tracked in Mandrill so you can verify that they are working.

The last thing you want to have happen is that emails from your non-production environments actually get sent to real users.

The way I typically do things is to have my development system use a non-test key, but only have dummy users whose email addresses all come back to me so I can test things. Then in my staging system, I use a test key with real users (a copy of the production user database) so that any emails that get sent are captured by Mandrill for verification that they are working, but don't ever get forwarded on to the actual user.

I'm assuming that your rejection rule based on a list of domains is intended to achieve the same result that using a test key does - in which case, go with the test keys and forget the rules.

You can't apply a rule to a specific sub account - only to a specific API key.

And no, you can't reroute an email to a different address based on the outcome of a rule - the best you could so is to wire a webhook to somehow notify your system that the rule was triggered so that your system can re-send the email - but that requires custom development work.

Again, if this is actually just an attempt to avoid sending emails to real users when testing, this is what test keys are for.